# Fan not working and overheating for my Saturn

Tags: cooling-system, car, saturn, fan

I currently have a 2003 Saturn lw200 2.2l and recently discovered it overheating and found that fan has not kicked on. I was conflicted and did some research and found out about troubleshooting the fan and I did and it worked but the next thing is that I replaced the engine temp sensor and still acted the same. My temp gauge fluctuates up and down and I thought it was the thermostat but still not the case at this point I don't know what it could be. I heard of the relay but I look at my relay box for the fan relay and wasn't there - there was no fan relay. I found the fan 1 and fan 2 fuse but they weren't blown. Would you guys have any idea what I could do to fix this problem for my fan to run or where I can locate the fan relay? I couldn't find it under the passenger side either. I'm left at this case thinking it's a clogged radiator but that has nothing to do with the fan. Thank you for your help and answers. If you are having the same problem don't be afraid to respond.

Comment: Hi and welcome.  You wrote that you tried some troubleshooting and "it worked".  What troubleshooting steps did you take and define "it worked".

Comment: I jumped the fan with alligator clips from the battery directly into the fan. The fan start but took it off died out this was just to test if it worked or if it was even good you know? It's still a problem but I'm feeling like it is a relay but can't locate it the only thing I can find is 2 fan fuses

Comment: Is there perhaps more than one relay/fuse panel? Do you have a graphic of the panel(s)?